# How to add Image to the Custom List View in Android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom list view with image view and text view.I am loading text view data from SQLite Database and I want to add image from my drawable folder to the image view contain in list based on some condition
I am using cursor to load data to the list view.Please any one guide me how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple solution for that,using a simple adapter.

```
public class TestList extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> arrlist = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        Map<String, String> m = null;
        for (int i = 0; i <=50; i++) {
            m = new HashMap<String, String>();
            m.put("key", String.valueOf(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

            m.put("title", "Title-" + i);

            m.put("subtitle", "SubTitle-" + i);

            arrlist.add(m);
        }
        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, arrlist,
                R.layout.sample, new String[] { "key", "title", "subtitle" },
                new int[] { R.id.imageView1, R.id.title, R.id.subtitle });

        list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

Xml layouts: main xml layout has a listview with id-list,and sample.xml is your inflating layout,it has one image,two textviews.Modify the code as your requirement.

Comment: But this add a same image to all items. I want to change the icon based on Title

Comment: int[] ids=new int[50]{R.drawable.icon1,R.drawable.icon2,R.drawable.icon3.......}; m.put("key", String.valueOf(ids[i]));